# Best Javascript video player Internet Explorer 6 compatible

Tags: javascript, video, internet-explorer-6, video-streaming, media-player

I'd like to insert in a website a video...The problem is:

- It must be accessible from IE6
- It must be accessible from IPad and apple devices (NO FLASH and no mediaplayer activex)

Anibody knows 'bout a solution to my problem?

The library or the code must be free!

Thank you very much!

Solved: using Hybrid approach, with apps like this:
http://camendesign.com/web-dev/video_for_everybody

Comment: "It must be accessible from IE6"... scary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no player that satisfies your conditions. You'll have to take a hybrid approach, with a combination of Flash and HTML 5 video.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML5!
example:

```
<video src="movie.ogg" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You just need to tweak it a little. Here is a little help: http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/

Comment: This is why you need to "tweak" it a bit with JS. (Check out the link) :)

Comment: That link is not a solution; it won't magically give IE 6 the ability to turn <video> tags into video players. It'll merely allow it to be recognised as an element, nothing more.

Comment: OK sorry for the wrong info. Use Flash and HTML5 together. Like @Delan said.